# Mocking Axios method on class using Nock.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, tdd, axios

I am pretty new to writing unit tests, and I'm struggling to work out how I should test a method on an es6 class that makes a axios request. I've been trying to use nock for this but the test passes regardless of the assertion. this is what I have been trying to do so far -

```
let dataService = new DataService;

describe('Data module with correct input', function () {
  before(function(){
    nock('https://random.newsapis.com')
      .get('search?section=recent-news&api-key=###############')
      .reply(200, 'Mock - response');
  });

  it('Should get a response from the server', function (done){
    dataService.getData('recent-news')
      .then(function(data){
        expect(data).to.equal('Mock - response');
      }).catch(err => {
        throw(err)
      });
    done();
  });
});
```

I've tried moving the done function in to the callback but to no avail. This is the pattern that I have used for other async code. I've had a look in to moxios but can't work out how to use it in the context of mocking a call in another module.

This is my `DataService` if that helps at all :

```
export default class dataService {
  getData = (section: string) => (
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      axios.get('https://random.newsapis.com/search?section=' + section + '&api-key=xxxx')
        .then(function (response) {
          return resolve(response.data.response);
        })
        .catch(function (reject) {
          errorModule(reject);
        });
     })
  )}
```

I appreciate any pointers that anybody can give me on this! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if nock works but you can use [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter).

```
const axios = require('axios');
const MockAdapter = require('axios-mock-adapter');

let dataService = new DataService;

describe('Data module with correct input', () => {
  let mock;

  before(() => {
    mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    mock.reset();
  });

  after(() => {
    mock.restore();
  });

  it('Should get a response from the server', async () => {
    mock.onGet('https://random.newsapis.com/search?section=recent-news&api-key=###############')
      .reply(200, 'Mock - response');

    const data = await dataService.getData('recent-news');
    expect(data).to.equal('Mock - response');
  });
});
```

I used async/await for the test, if you want to use callbacks make sure `done` is called inside the `then` and `catch` block:

```
dataService.getData('recent-news')
  .then(function(data){
    expect(data).to.equal('Mock - response');
    done();
  }).catch(err => {
    done(err);
  });
```